# Running JSF 2.0 on Servlet 2.4 container

Tags: jsf, tomcat, servlets, jboss, jsf-2

As far as I know, JSF 2 requires servlet 2.5, so it doesn't run on JBOSS 4.05 (Tomcat 5.5). Unfortunately I have to deploy an application who uses JSF 2.0 and Primefaces on that environment.

Is there any hack to use that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JSF 2.0 depends heavily on [EL 2.1](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/package-summary.html) which is part of Servlet 2.5 and is a major change as opposed to [EL 2.0](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/el/package-summary.html) which is part of Servlet 2.4, but it does not depend on any particular Servlet 2.5 specific API. Servlet 2.4 should work as good. So in theory, you could get JSF 2.0 to work on Servlet 2.4 if you provide your own EL 2.1 API and implementation in `/WEB-INF/lib`. I did a quick test here on Tomcat 5.5.33 with the following libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib`:

- `el-api.jar` file copied from `lib` folder of [Tomcat 6.0.x](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi)
- [`jboss-el.jar`](https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/jboss-releases/org/jboss/seam/jboss-el/2.0.0.GA/jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar) file (implements EL 2.1 and supports EL 2.2 like method invocation with arguments)
- `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar` from [Mojarra 2.0.x](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html)

And a Servlet 2.4 `web.xml` where the JBoss EL is been declared:

```
<context-param>     
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

A simple JSF 2.0 Facelet (not JSP!) with a simple `<h:form>` with a button with `<f:ajax>` and a simple `@ViewScoped` `@ManagedBean` works for me on Tomcat 5.5.33. Give it a try on your JBoss 4.0.5 and test it thoroughly.

Note that you need a minimum of JDK 1.5, not JDK 1.4. Also note that your application is this way unportable to any Servlet 3.0 container due to presence of the Servlet 2.5 specific `el-api.jar` file.

Comment: Good man, thanks!
But I still have a problem - Primefaces didn't worked with that approach. The error: Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling [jar:file:/HIDDEN/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/./tmp/deploy/tmp1314317090148712617primefaces-test-exp.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.0.M2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/primefaces-p.taglib.xml@5,17]

Comment: Try PrimeFaces 2.x. The 3.0 has Servlet 3.0 specific dependencies.