# RichFaces on Weblogic 9.2.1

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, weblogic

I´ve tried deploy an application on Weblogic 9.2.1 and I´ve received this error:

```
org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlSubTable
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.FacesException: Cant instantiate class: org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlSubTable.
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:545)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.verifyObjects(ConfigureListener.java:1302)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:397)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:376)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
javax.faces.FacesException: Cant instantiate class: org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlSubTable.
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.newThing(ApplicationImpl.java:1016)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.verifyObjects(ConfigureListener.java:1302)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:397)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:376)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/component/visit/VisitContext
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2395)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1763)
        at java.beans.Introspector$1.run(Introspector.java:1265)
        at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1263)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I´ve tried a lot of things to solve this problem, but so far I didn´t understand this problem. I checked my libs on WEB-INF/lib and the libs were correct.
I think this problem occurs due the Weblogic´s libraries JSF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/component/visit/VisitContext
> ```

This is [JSF 2.0 specific](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/visit/VisitContext.html) which in turn requires a Servlet 2.5 container with the `web.xml` declared conform Servlet 2.5 spec. I don't do Weblogic, so I can't tell from top of head, but Google learns me that Weblogic 9.2.x is a Servlet 2.4 container.

So, JSF 2.0 is not going to work on Weblogic 9.2.x out the box anyway. You have 2 options:

1. Upgrade the container to a Servlet 2.5 capable make/version. E.g. Weblogic 10.x, Glassfish 2.x, JBoss AS 5.x, Tomcat 6.x etc. Servlet 2.5 is already out over 5 years ago.
2. Downgrade JSF 2.0 to JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 4.x to RichFaces 3.x. When using [Facelets](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html) instead of JSP, it should work on Servlet 2.4.

You can *in theory* however hack your JSF 2.0 webapp with specific libs to get it to run on servlet 2.4 containers. I only don't guarantee that it will work flawlessly on Weblogic along with RichFaces.

- [Running JSF 2.0 on Servlet 2.4 container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998447/running-jsf-2-0-on-servlet-2-4-container)

Answer (score 0):

Cound be a conflict with the WebLogic JARs.  Either remove yours or tell WebLogic to prefer classes found in the WEB-INF/lib using `<prefer-web-inf-classes>`:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html

Comment: Hello duffymo. I´ll try your suggestion!