# Steps to deploy latest JSF version in weblogic 10.3

Tags: jsf-2, netbeans-6.9, weblogic-10.x

I am going to start working on a new project and I am considering to use JSF latest version but our weblogic server version is 10.3 and I am not sure what are all the steps to follow to deploy JSF 2 application in weblogic 10.3 And also would like to know the IDE which supports to develop JSF2 applications. Currently I am using weblogic 10g workshop but it doesnt support the latest JSF version.

Can someone tell me the steps to:

1. Develop JSF 2 applications in Oracle workshop/Netbeans 6.9.1
2. Deploy the JSF 2 application in Weblogic 10.3

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 11):

*Disclaimer: I don't do Weblogic or Netbeans, the answer below is partly based on Google research.*

Here are some facts:

- JSF 2.0 requires at least a Servlet 2.5 container ([although you can in theory hack it for Servlet 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998447/running-jsf-2-0-on-servlet-2-4-container)).
- JSF 2.1 requires at least a Servlet 3.0 container.
- Weblogic 10.3.x is a Servlet 2.5 container, so JSF 2.1 is never going to work out the box.

As per the [release notes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wlw/docs103/relnotes/relnotes.html) which I found by [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=weblogic%2010.3%20servlet%20version), Weblogic 10.3 is a Servlet 2.5 container which ships with JSF 1.2 built in. As per [this blog](http://blog.eisele.net/2010/04/weblogic-server-10330-released-it-now.html) which I found by [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=weblogic%2010.3%20jsf%202.0), Weblogic 10.3.3 ships with built in JSF 2.0 support. The blog contains detailed information about how to get Weblogic 10.3.3 running with JSF 2.0.

As to the IDE, I have no idea about Oracle Workshop, but according to [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=netbeans%20jsf%202.0), Netbeans seems to already support JSF 2.0 since version 6.8. In order to get JSF 2.0 features to work properly, you only have to ensure that the `web.xml` complies with Servlet 2.5 and that the `faces-config.xml` complies with JSF 2.0.

Comment: Thanks. I was initially planning to use JSF2.0 for developing the current project but after googling I found weblogic 10.3.0 will not support JSF 2 so I implemented using JSF 1.2. Even as per the blog it says only 10.3.3 supports JSF 2.0. But in my next project I prefer to use JSF 2.0 but I am not able to find out any steps on how to deploy JSF 2.0 application in weblogic 10.3.0 anywhere.

Comment: So it's not an option to upgrade to 10.3.3 as per the blog's instructions?

Comment: No that is not an option but I can decide what framework I can use to implement the new application.

Comment: A comment on the linked blog mentions that there's no way to get it to run on 10.3.0. You might want to try a forum dedicated to Weblogic to be sure or to learn if there are ways/hacks.