# oracle weblogic 10.3 is not recognizing the code

Tags: jsf-2, weblogic-10.x

I am new to JSF 2.1
I have imported one project built on JSF 2.1 in oracle weblogic 10.3. I have removed all the errors and build was successful, But the code is not getting recognized in this tool.

I want to know that is there any **JAR** required??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF 2.1 requires Servlet 3.0 and WebLogic 10.3 supports Servlet 2.5. You might also have problems with the JPA version, depending on your project configuration. Take a look into your managed server logs to see if that is the case. Also, please see this related question: [Migrating JSF 2.1 application from Glassfish 3 to Weblogic 10.x or 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8397767/347777)