# How can I check what version of EL is server using

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, el

How can I check what version of EL is server using .
I am running Websphere 7 . EL classes are in j2ee.jar and manifest is below.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: 2.4 (IBM Corporation)
Specification-Title: Java Platform, Enterprise Edition Specification
Specification-Version: 5.0
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
Implementation-Title: Java Platform, Enterprise Edition Specification
Implementation-Version: 5.0
Implementation-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
Class-Path: activation-impl.jar mail-impl.jar
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

EL version goes hand in hand with Servlet/JSP version which is dependent on the servletcontainer implementation/version used and also on the `web.xml` root declaration of your webapp.

- Servlet 5.0 comes with JSP 3.0 and EL 4.0 (Jakarta EE 9).
- Servlet 4.0 comes with JSP 2.3 and EL 3.0 (Java EE 8).
- Servlet 3.1 comes with JSP 2.3 and EL 3.0 (Java EE 7).
- Servlet 3.0 comes with JSP 2.2 and EL 2.2 (Java EE 6).
- Servlet 2.5 comes with JSP 2.1 and EL 2.1 (Java EE 5).
- Servlet 2.4 comes with JSP 2.0 and EL 2.0 (J2EE 1.4).
- Servlet 2.3 comes with JSP 1.2 without EL (J2EE 1.3). EL is to be provided by JSTL 1.0 and works inside JSTL tags only.

WebSphere 7 is a Java EE 5 certified container which thus implies Servlet 2.5 which in turn thus comes with JSP/EL 2.1. However, if the `web.xml` of your webapp is declared conform for example Servlet 2.4, then your webapp will run in Servlet 2.4 modus with JSP/EL 2.0.

Since you tagged this JSF, I guess that the sole purpose of this question is to figure out if you could use the new EL 2.2 feature of being able to invoke non-getter methods with arguments in EL. That's thus not natively supported by your container. However, you could install [JBoss EL](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest-2.2/reference/en-US/html/elenhancements.html) as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328) to get it to work on Servlet 2.5 containers.

#### See also:

- [Difference between JSP EL, JSF EL and Unified EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el)

Comment: What JSF specification item exactly are you asking about? I didn't mention anything in my answer. Please note that JSF and Servlet/JSP/EL are not closely coupled with each other. If you'd like to learn about the minimum required Servlet/JSP API for a certain JSF version, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206719/highest-supported-jsf-version-for-jboss-4-0/7207281#7207281).