# How to know which version of EL is getting used?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, tomcat7, el

I am developing a webstore as a pet project and converting JSP pages that use scriptlets to EL and JSTL based JSP pages. I am using NetBeans and Tomcat 7. My question is how can I know which version of EL is getting used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Tomcat installation, go to the `/lib` directory, and open the `el-api.jar` file with a ZIP manager. Under `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, you'll find something like

```
Specification-Version: 2.2
```

That's your EL version.

Apparently the version of EL go with the version of the Servlet API. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237000/how-can-i-check-what-version-of-el-is-server-using).