# p:graphicImage gives NoSuchMethodError after migrating from 5.3 to 6.0 Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am using Primefaces 6.0 on Weblogic11g,JSF2.0,Servlet 2.5.

My Application was able to render dynamic jpeg images with Primefaces 5.3. Once i migrated to 6.0, my dynamic p:graphicImages are giving NoSuchMethodError related to el.

> PrimeExceptionHandler logException
>   javax.el.ValueExpression.getValueReference(Ljavax/el/ELContext;)Ljavax/el/ValueReference;
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.el.ValueExpression.getValueReference(Ljavax/el/ELContext;)Ljavax/el/ValueReference;
>     at
>   org.primefaces.el.ValueExpressionAnalyzer.toValueReference(ValueExpressionAnalyzer.java:91)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.el.ValueExpressionAnalyzer.getExpression(ValueExpressionAnalyzer.java:44)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.util.DynamicResourceBuilder.build(DynamicResourceBuilder.java:58)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImageRenderer.getImageSrc(GraphicImageRenderer.java:75)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImageRenderer.encodeEnd(GraphicImageRenderer.java:41)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:884)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1681)
>     at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:854)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
>   e

```
@ManagedBean(name="filebean")
@RequestScoped


public class FileBean {

private StreamedContent image;

public StreamedContent getImage() {
    try {
        File file = new File("C:/LEAVEMODULEFOLDER/569_q318d09lou9mafbqsdgsqph1ar_cbblogopng.jpg");

        System.out.println(""+file.canRead());
        image = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(file), "image/jpeg");

} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error in ::" + e);
    log.error(Utility.getStackTrace(e));
}



return this.image;
}
}
```

xhtml code is as follows

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{filebean.image}" />
```

Comment: Did you check the releasenotes/migration guide?

Comment: Yes, i did, but found nothing which was relevent for me except changing the primefaces jar file.

Comment: Any lead that can help ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html#getValueReference(javax.el.ELContext)) the method in question (`ValueExpression.getValueReference()`) does only exist since EL 2.2

Since you are using Servlet 2.5, you are most likely using EL 2.1 (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7237216/2320245) for more information). Therefore the `NoSuchMethodError` occurs for the EL 2.2 method.

So the only options you seem to have is either staying with PrimeFaces 5.3, upgrading to EL 2.2/Servlet 3.0 or not using `p:graphicImage` anymore.

Apart from that you could also report this issue to the PrimeFaces devs, because since they seem to support Servlet 2.5 according to their user guide, this might be considered a bug.

Comment: Thank you. I will report it to Primefaces.

Comment: Primefaces accepted this as an enhancement request https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1859