# JSF displays EL expressions as plain text instead of evaluated value

Tags: java, jsf, el

I'm trying to create an "Hello World" JSF application.
I have a bean with one field (String).

```
@ManagedBean (name = "beanTest")
@SessionScoped
public class BeanTest
{
    private String myString = "myString";
    public String getMyString()
    {
        return myString;
    }
    public void setMyString(String myString)
    {
        this.myString = myString;
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to display the string value in my JSP page

```html
<h:outputLabel value="#{beanTest.myString}"/>
```

In the webpage it displayed `"#{beanTest.myString}"` instead of `"myString"`

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can happen if your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 2.4 or older, or if your `/WEB-INF/lib` folder is cluttered with servletcontainer specific libraries like `el-api.jar`, etc of an older version.

Make sure that the `web.xml` root declaraton conforms at least Servlet 2.5 or preferably the highest Servlet API version supported by your container and that the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder does not contain any servletcontainer specific libraries.

Comment: So would this be because the app doesn't know how to handle EL expressions?

Comment: @Zack: That's correct. The EL API has changed in Servlet 2.4 and 2.5. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el for a bit of history. The OP's problem indicate that he's basically using an incompatible EL API and thus all expressions won't (can't) be resolved.

Comment: You are right. I changed my web.xml from 2.4 to 2.5 and now everything works like a charm. How can I work with version 2.4?

Comment: Either downgrade to JSF 1.2 or provide your own EL implementation (I don't guarantee 100% that this hack will work in all containers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998447/running-jsf-2-0-on-servlet-2-4-container/5998625#5998625)

Answer (score 0):

use `h:outputtext` for this purpose

Comment: While h:outputLabel is indeed the wrong tag for the purpose, it won't make any difference in the concrete problem.

Comment: @BalusC, you are true. I should delete this answer.