# Minimum required Tomcat version for JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2.2, minimum-requirements

I would like to upgrade my JSF 1.2 application to JSF 2.2. What's the minimum required Tomcat version for JSF 2.2? I'm currently using Tomcat 5. Is it possible to run JSF 2.2 on it?

Answer (score 6):

JSF 2.2 requires a Servlet 3.0 compatible container, mainly because of the new [`<h:inputFile>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/inputFile.html) component which requires container-native file upload support. [This was only introduced in Servlet 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824).

If you check the [Tomcat versions overview](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), then you'll see that you need minimally Tomcat 7.x in order to have a Servlet 3.0 compatible container.

---

> *So what's the latest version I can update JSF to?*

You're not terribly clear on the exact Tomcat version you're currently using (5.0.x vs 5.5.x is quite a difference), but if it is Tomcat 5.5.x, then you could run JSF 2.0/2.1 on it if you supply a custom EL 2.1 compatible implementation along the webapp itself. See also the answer on [Running JSF 2.0 on Servlet 2.4 container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998447/running-jsf-2-0-on-servlet-2-4-container).

Comment: So what's the latest version I can update JSF to? I mean if it's possible to update to JSF 2.0.

Comment: BTW, if I'm using rich-faces 3.3 will I have to update it up to 4.0?

Comment: This is not related to the current question. Press "Ask Question" to ask a new question.